# How can I get query from listing Big Query Jobs?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I'm trying to retrive query from job.list for each job but JobConfiguration dosen't have that field.

```
BigQuery bigQuery = bigqueryClientServiceFactory.getClientService(dataStoreId);

        Page<Job> listJobs = bigQuery.listJobs(JobListOption.pageSize(100),JobListOption.fields(JobField.values()));
        for(Job job:listJobs.iterateAll()){
            com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobConfiguration configuration = job.getConfiguration();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `JobConfiguration` to a `QueryJobConfiguration` and call the `getQuery()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        Page<Job> listJobs = bigquery.listJobs(BigQuery.JobListOption.pageSize(100));
        for(Job job:listJobs.iterateAll()){
            if (job.getConfiguration() instanceof QueryJobConfiguration){
                QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = job.getConfiguration();
                System.out.println(queryConfig.getQuery());
            }
        }
    }
```